# htaccess seo issue

Tags: opencart

I am running OpenCart 2.0.1.1 and would like to turn on the SEO URLs option.

In the admin panel, I navigated to system -> settings, clicked the edit button then clicked the Server tab and selected Yes to turn on the "Use SEO URLs" and saved changes.

In the public_html folder, I renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

Refreshed website and no change. If I go to a product page, I am still 
getting this:

```
example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=297
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
If the keyword seo on the Data Tab contains no keyword, then the above default
format is used for the url.